# How to export large JSON data to Excel in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have working in a project where from API we are getting large JSON Data(more than 40K). The data is being converted to XLSX file in the client side created using Angular when client is clicking on "Export to excel" button. The code works fine when the Data is less than 10K, but in case of large amount of data, we are unable to export the excel file. Here is the code for generating excel file using Sheet JS library.

```js
let timeValue = this.serverDateTimeFormat();
this.fileName = selectedDb.toLowerCase() + '-' +   
                selectedTbl.toLowerCase() + '-' + timeValue + '.xlsx';
let element = data;
                 
const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet =XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.exportDatas);
const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');
XLSX.writeFile(wb, this.fileName);
```

Any expert opinion?

Comment: Errors..? Anyway, not exactly a good idea to do this in the browser probably..

Comment: Are you getting an error message?  You say you're not able to export, but you didn't say what's happening instead.

Comment: I have debugged and found out that, data is coming. But while running "XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet" function, it is getting stuck and do not work. It works fine when data is less than 10K

Comment: You're likely running up on client browser limitations.  Setting up a node.js server specifically for handling Excel exports would be pretty simple to do.